# How to find woeid (where on earth id) of a country

Tags: python, api, twitter, trend

I am trying to test Twitter API and find trends in a country.
How can I find the WOEID (WHERE ON EARTH IDENTIFIER) for a specific country?
I tried looking on Google but could not find a list.

If there is any program in Python that provides WOEID that is fine as well.

Comment: Have you seen [it](http://www.woeidlookup.com/)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [yweather](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yweather/0.1) package provides a way of doing this:

```
>>> import yweather
>>> client = yweather.Client()
>>> client.fetch_woeid('Australia')
'23424748'
```

Comment: The only official pip package I found that gets woeid and works.. The link above is for v0.1. I found v0.1.1 ready and working - so download from the 'latest' url https://pypi.org/project/yweather/

Comment: package seems to be obsolete. Code don't working. `HTTP Error 502: Cannot find server.`

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I've tried local and in colab, maybe those versions are not supported.

Comment: @LuisFelipe my apologies, i thought you meant the pypi link. you're right, it has been deprecated: `As of Thursday, Jan. 3, 2019, the weather.yahooapis.com and query.yahooapis.com for Yahoo Weather API will be retired.`